# Excluir item de um array Inioc 2

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, ionic2, arraylist

Estou tendo dificuldade para entender como funciona o método splice(). Preciso excluir itens de um array, quando clica no (x), ex:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of data">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col width-50>
        {{item.nameFruit}}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-50 text-right (click)="delItem(item)">
        X
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-item>
```

Typescript:

`delItem(id){
  let elemento = this.data.splice(0,id);
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O splice aceita o index de inicio no primeiro argumento e o numero de elementos a remover no segundo argumento. No teu caso deve ser `.splice(index, 1)`, que na prática é:

```
delItem(item){
   const index = this.data.indexOf(item);
   const elementoRemovido = this.data.splice(index, 1);
   // aqui podes fazer algo com o item removido
   // a array modifica-se a si própria com o splice
}
```

Mais sobre [`.splice()` na **MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=control) <sup>(em inglês)</sup>